# Swift iOS: Unable to Upload Image to AWS S3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So, I've created an S3 bucket with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "User_ARN"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "Buckent_ARN"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1569218242333",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "User_ARN"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "Buckent_ARN/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also created a Cognito Identity Pool & an IAM user. Now, I'm trying to upload an image to my bucket from my app and am getting: 
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 2.)

In my AppDelegate I'm setting up with the following:

```swift
 let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.usWest2,
           identityPoolId:"us-west-2:XXXXX")

        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.usWest2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

and trying to upload my image like this:

```swift
if let imageToUpload =  self.myImage {
    let awsTransferUtilitytransferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    let s3BucketName = "my-bucket"

    let pngImage = imageToUpload.pngData()
    let filename = "someImage.png"
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(filename)
    do {
        try pngImage?.write(to: fileURL)

        awsTransferUtilitytransferUtility.uploadData(pngImage!, bucket: s3BucketName, key: filename, contentType: "img/png", expression: nil) { (uploadTask, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error is: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Task Result: \(uploadTask)")
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print("File not saved!")
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is a permissions issue, because I created a public bucket and was able to upload the image without a problem.  I'm new to AWS and the permissions are very confusing to me.  I created an IAM role, which I've assigned to the bucket policy and I've setup a Cognito Identity Pool.  But, what's the link between Cognito & IAM?  Do I need to provide IAM credentials in my code to upload?  I've done my setup with the following article:  https://medium.com/@haydnjmorris/uploading-photos-to-aws-s3-getting-started-with-cognito-and-iam-c96ba5b5496d

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is your app? In EC2? Have you set the s3 vpc endpoint for private access?

Comment: @Lamanus the app is an iOS app running on an iPhone.

Comment: Then how to upload a file from your app to the private bucket? It is private and should have same vpc.

Comment: @Lamanus I'm not sure I understand, so because it's a secure bucket, I can't upload to it from an app?  I'm relatively certain that Cognito can be used for auth to the bucket.

Comment: Oh, I see that there is a principal for User ARN. It might be from cognito, right?

Comment: Have you set the cognito role correctly? please check the [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/).

Comment: @DavidB, Have you resolved the issue?